# How to Customize my Lightning Flow Called From Lightning component

Tags: lightning, visual-flows

When i give an managed package to customers i should give them the flexibility to create a new lightning flow with 'n' number of inputs and 'n' number of outputs and allow them to fill the flow name in some field .so that i can read the flow from my Lightning component. How should i pass that 'n' number of inputs and get 'n' number of outputs from my lightning component to/from the flow?